# Encoding problems with @RequestHeader

Tags: spring, spring-boot, encoding

I am trying to get a header value which contains Turkish characters like "ı,ğ,ü,ş,ö,ç". I tried adding ISO-8859-1 encoding support to spring boot configuration but couldn't succeeded. Here is application.properties file content

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=ISO-8859-1
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.http.encoding.force-request=true
spring.http.encoding.force-response=true
```

And here is a sample post mapping that takes name parameter as request header.

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/hello", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> samplePost(@RequestHeader("name") String name)  {
        System.out.println("name : " + name);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

You can find a sample curl and System.out.println result below

Curl:

```
curl -X POST   http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/hello   -H 'Accept: application/json'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'   -H 'name: ığüşöç'
```

Output:

```
name : Ä±ÄÃ¼ÅÃ¶Ã§
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should use url-encoding in http-headers:

```
$ curl -X POST   http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/hello   -H 'Accept: application/json'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'   -H 'name: %C4%B1%C4%9F%C3%BC%C5%9F%C3%B6%C3%A7'
```

```
package pro.kretov.spring.boot;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/hello", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> samplePost(@RequestHeader("name") String name) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        System.out.println("name : " + URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello " + URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Response:

```
Hello ığüşöç
```

application.properties is empty.

Comment: Hi Wexx, Thank you for the response but the result of System.out.println is still same. I also use "ISO-8859-1" charset but the result not changed.